# How does chown work with regards to files created by Mac OS X?

Tags: dual-boot, permissions, macosx

I have a 1 TB hard drive in a Macbook Pro 6,2 (mid-2010) partitioned with 900 GB for Mac OS X and 100 GB for Ubuntu 14.04. I wanted to make the HFS+ partition (with OS X installed as a boot drive) readable from Ubuntu. I followed [another user's answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/619820/trouble-accessing-mac-os-x-partition-from-ubuntu-14-04) and did this:

```
sudo mkdir -R /media/username/MacOS
sudo chown --recursive username:username /media/username
sudo mount -t hfsplus -o uid=USERUID,gid=USERGID /dev/sdx /media/username/MacOS
```

The `chown` step seems to go through every file on the HFS+ partition (mounted at /media/username/MacOS) and changes ownership to the user indicated by username. After each change, the process says "Read-only file system". When I access the MacOS partition using `sudo nautilus`, the files are also read-only.

Based on my research, this is good; HFS+ is supposed to be read-only for Ubuntu unless journaling is turned off, so it seems to be operating as it should. My question, then, is what is `chown` actually changing? Is it changing the permissions of the files on the HFS+ partition itself, or is it just changing whether Ubuntu gives access to those (read-only) files to my user? In other words, is `chown` actually making any changes to my Mac OS X files/permissions? Can `chown` make changes to permissions on a drive that is read-only?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`chown` cannot make changes to read-only filesystems.

Comment: So, when I execute `chown` on a mounted HFS+ parition (for example, my OS X boot drive with my files) and I then have access to read from Ubuntu, it's not modifying the mac files? I know it might be a stupid question, but I'm not sure why it works given that the drive is read-only.